# Enlarging array and filling with value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, resize, fill

What is the best way to enlarge a numpy 1D array and fill the new space with the last value.

F.e.

```
 a = [1,2,3]
 ... enlarge ..to size 5 ...
 a = [1,2,3,3,3]
```

---

```
    vals = list(seq)
    vals.extend( [seq[-1]] * diff )
    seq = np.array(vals )
```

Comment: Don't think in terms of enlarging an array.  Think about making a new array with the desired values, both the fill and the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy `pad`, like this:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10
a = np.array([1,2,3])

a = np.pad(a, (0, N-len(a)), 'edge')

# array([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
b = np.ones(5, dtype=a.dtype)*a[-1]
b[:len(a)] = a
```

output:

```
[1 2 3 3 3]
```